# How to resolve dependency issues in cabal project?

Tags: haskell, cabal

This is a follow-up question to "How to convert a stack project into a cabal project?" and answered by @leftaroundabout. I created a stack project that seems to build. And now that I want to build the same project using cabal, some dependency issues arise.
Here are some lines from package.yaml:

```
dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- containers >= 0.6.0.1 && < 0.7
- persistent >= 2.12.0.1 && < 2.14.0.0
library:
  source-dirs: src

executables:
  TMS-exe:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - TMS
    - containers >= 0.6.0.1 && < 0.7
    - persistent >= 2.12.0.1 && < 2.14.0.0
```

Here are the dependency issues with package persistent:

```
PS C:\Users\ephra\OneDrive\Dokument\haskell\mena-projects\TMS> cabal v2-build
Resolving dependencies...
cabal.exe: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: TMS-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] trying: persistent-2.13.3.0 (dependency of TMS)
[__2] next goal: template-haskell (dependency of persistent)
[__2] rejecting: template-haskell-2.18.0.0/installed-2.18.0.0 (conflict:
persistent => template-haskell>=2.13 && <2.18)
[__2] skipping: template-haskell-2.18.0.0 (has the same characteristics that
caused the previous version to fail: excluded by constraint '>=2.13 && <2.18'
from 'persistent')
[__2] rejecting: template-haskell-2.17.0.0, template-haskell-2.16.0.0,
template-haskell-2.15.0.0, template-haskell-2.14.0.0,
template-haskell-2.13.0.0, template-haskell-2.12.0.0,
template-haskell-2.11.1.0, template-haskell-2.11.0.0,
template-haskell-2.10.0.0, template-haskell-2.9.0.0, template-haskell-2.8.0.0,
template-haskell-2.7.0.0, template-haskell-2.6.0.0, template-haskell-2.5.0.0,
template-haskell-2.4.0.1, template-haskell-2.4.0.0, template-haskell-2.3.0.1,
template-haskell-2.3.0.0, template-haskell-2.2.0.0 (constraint from
non-upgradeable package requires installed instance)
[__2] fail (backjumping, conflict set: persistent, template-haskell)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: persistent, TMS, template-haskell
```

Comment: `template-haskell` is one of the packages bundled with GHC. `t-h-2.18.0.0` is bundled with GHC 9.2.1, which I assume is the GHC version you're using. `persistent` isn't compatible with `t-h-2.18` and GHC 9.2 yet. This is a typical problem when you're using the latest GHC. I suggest you go with an older GHC, 8.10 or 9.0. `ghcup list` currently recommends 8.10.7.

Comment: You could also try `cabal v2-build --allow-newer=template-haskell` – often packages actually build flawlessly with dependencies outside the upper version bound. But in this case the chance is rather high that it would fail.